# Some way to send data from one FTP server to another without intermediary?

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, ftp-server

I'm trying to move a large amount of files from one CDN to another. I know that they have a very high-speed connection to each other, so what I'd like to do is connect them directly, but the only protocol I have access to with each is FTP. Is there any way to log into the current CDN and send their files to the other FTP? It seems like it should be possible, I just have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FXP: see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol). Powerful FTP clients are capable of doing this. From protocol point of view it's trivial.

BTW this question is probably offtopic here.

Comment: Does that require something to be enabled on the server side? I'm getting a 425 Bad Ip Connecting error

Comment: @UltimateBrent In general, if the servers are not behind firewall, nothing should be set up explicitly. The client software must deal with this automatically. If one or both servers are behind the firewall, the things become much more complicated though. But as said, this question should be asked on http://superuser.com or on http://serverfault.com, there you will get more detailed and experienced answer. I know how the protocol works, but now how to configure various servers and clients for FXP.